# How to move JPEG files according to file names in a CSV file from one folder to another folder?

Tags: batch-file

I have the folder `%UserProfile%\Desktop\SourceImages` with 10,000 JPEG files. I have a CSV file in same folder that lists the `.jpeg` files which I want to move to `%UserProfile%\Desktop\SelectedImages`.

Example:

The lists of file names in `FileList.csv` is as follows:

```
01234567.txt
01234568.txt
```

The file `FileList.csv` and the two `.txt` files are stored in `%UserProfile%\Desktop\SourceImages`.

I need to create a batch file running on Windows 11 to read the CSV file and move the files to `%UserProfile%\Desktop\SelectedImages`.

I saw a posting with the following code but it does not move the files to the folder.

```
@echo off
set "theDir=%UserProfile%\Desktop\SourceImages"
for /F "delims=" %%f in (FileList.csv) do (
    copy %theDir%\%%f.* "%UserProfile%\Desktop\SelectedImages"
)
```

Comment: The task can be done with following single command line in the batch file: `@for /F "usebackq eol=| delims=" %%I in ("%UserProfile%\Desktop\SourceImages\FileList.csv") do @move "%UserProfile%\Desktop\SourceImages\%%~nI.*" "%UserProfile%\Desktop\SelectedImages\" >nul`. There is used the command `move` instead of `copy` and there is used the modifier `%%~n` to get just the file name without file extension of current file read from the CSV file which is concatenated with `.*` to a wildcard pattern.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick example for you to try, *(this one uses the `Robocopy.exe` utility to perform the file move, as opposed to the inbuilt `move` command. It means that if you decide that you really did want to COPY, instead of MOVE, you just need to remove the `/Mov` option on line `14`)*. The script also expects that none of the filenames in your list are quoted, as per your example content:

```bash
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

Set "SourceDir=%UserProfile%\Desktop\SourceImages"
Set "ListFile=%SourceDir%\FileList.csv"
Set "DestinationDir=%UserProfile%\Desktop\SelectedImages"

If Not Exist "%ListFile%" GoTo :EOF
Set "_="
PushD "%SourceDir%" 2>NUL && (Set "_=T") || GoTo :EOF

For /F "EOL=? Delims=" %%G In ('Dir . /B /A:-D 2^>NUL
 ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /L /I /X /G:"%ListFile%"'
) Do %SystemRoot%\System32\Robocopy.exe . "%DestinationDir%" "%%G" /Mov 1>NUL

If Defined _ PopD

EndLocal
GoTo :EOF
```

I will not explain how each command works, or what it does, I'll leave you to open a Command Prompt window, type each different command followed by its help option, e.g. `for /?`, `robocopy /?`, and press the <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key, to learn about each one.